# Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference but works in another server

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, server

I have a classic asp project. In one of my pages i have to call a javascript function. That call does not have any problem and works fine on my test server (not localhost, just a server to test he project). But when i deploy it to the actual server, that function does not work. I call this function in onload event.

That function has this type of lines (i cannot write the whole code, because of the company that i work for, does not allow it)

```
document.getElementById("R6C2_1").style.display = 'block'
document.getElementById("R6C2_2").style.display = 'none'
```

....

When I try to debug it on IE10, i got **"Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference"** error. After that, the elements in javascript function are not load. They are not seen on the page.

My main problem is, as i mentioned before differences between servers. I do not understand why it works on one server, but not on another server.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not enough info.How you call it ? Did you defined event listener, or you use window.onload ?

Comment: I call it on onload event listener in html body tag. But I think it does not relate to event listener or etc. Because same page works on another server, or similar pages with similar javascript functions works on both servers that I use. Just this page has problems and I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Switching servers can affect timing, meaning something runs very quickly in dev so you don't see the issue, but in live where server loading & comms differ you can find your code trying to access elements that have not yet arrived, then because of the the javascript on the page stops and the follow-on elements may never arrive. Modify your code to check if the expected element `R6C2_1` is present before you manipulate it, and show an error if not, e.g. `console.log("element R6C2_1 not found when expected!")`. That will confirm a timing issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's not possible to determine the issue from this information alone, you should look into:

1. Whether the elements you're looking for actually exist when the code is invoked (use browser debug / breakpoints to look at the page the moment the code is invoked).
2. If they exist, check if they have the ID you expect (e.g R6C2_1) - if not, why? who creates these IDs? could be a server configuration issue.
3. Do a debug using the app from each server, and look at the page / DOM, see if there are differences or check if the code is invoked at different times.

These could lead you to pinpoint the issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In case the elements just take time to be created, you can just wait until they are present:

```
function ExecuteWhenExists() {
    var R6C2_1 = document.getElementById("R6C2_1");
    var R6C2_2 = document.getElementById("R6C2_2");
    if (R6C2_1 && R6C2_2) {
        R6C2_1.style.display = 'block';
        R6C2_2.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(ExecuteWhenExists, 100);
    }
}
ExecuteWhenExists();
```

This will not crash when the elements do not exist, and will just keep trying to execute in a non-blocking way (polling every 0.1 seconds) until they exist.